# Sum of quarterly reports is not equal to annual reports

Tags: stocks, investing, banking, financial-statements

I am trying to calculate a stock's worth and in doing so I am adding values of all the four quarters from quarterly reports but it is not equal to the value in the annual report. I am trying to evaluate a bank's report.
[image]

The value there is in '000' so whenever I add `5,718,067,000` and `3,605,247,000` we get `9,323,314,000` and in annual report it shows `8,116,152,416`

[image]

Just by adding two quarters I get a value that is greater than in the annual report.

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post links to the raw financial statements? Are you certain they're reported in the same currency?

Comment: Financial statements are sometimes restated, for example to recharacterize amounts into different quarters. If you are viewing the numbers on a site that aggregates (not the company’s own site) you might see some numbers that aren’t restated.